# How to change the location of the Smarteyeglass API

Tags: sony, sony-smarteyeglass

I have an application working that I made using one of the samples as base (Advanced Layouts). I added some external modules that was added to the project just fine, but I can't manage to put the 3 folders of the API (SmartExtensionAPI, SmartExtensionUtils and SmartEyeglassAPI) inside the project.
The only place where the project can read the libs is on the same folder where the project is located (but outside of it).

```
$PROJECT_DIR$/../SmartExtensionAPI/SmartExtensionAPI.iml
```

If I try to remove the modules, gladle will re-add them. And if I remove them from gradle and re-add manually, it doesn't work and I get the following error.

```
Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

So I'm looking for the place where the project points for the API and change it, or a way to re-add these modules externally from another location.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to add APIs as modules in your project. Please see steps below:

1. Choose **File** > **New** > **Import Module**
2. Browse to the folder where APIs are stored > select the root folder of the API you want to add > click **OK** > click **Finish**. Import one API at a time.
3. Once you have added three APIs as modules. Choose **File** > **Project
   Structure**.
4. In the Project Structure window, select your application as the module where  you will import APIs.
5. In the Dependencies tab, click the plus-sign icon to add a dependency, and choose Module Dependency.
6. Add chose the APIs you just added as modules > click **OK**
7. In the Scope setting for the modules, select **Compile**

After the steps, all APIs should be imported to your project.

Hope this would help and let me know if it works.

Best,
/Emily - Sony

Answer (score 0):

Actually I figured it out, the answer was simpler than I thought. The project originally was using "includeFlat" to import the API modules. I just changed to a simple "include" and the project started recognizing the API folders inside the project.
Anyway, thank you for your help, Emily.